# How to logon as application using the facebook-c# SDK?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the facebook c# SDK v6. The demo Windows App from GitHub is working fine, I can logon as myself and post to my wall and the post says it comes from my app.

However, if I want to post a score for a user (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/) or get a list of scores to show a leader board I need to logon as the app, not the user. This is explained here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/.

So does anyone have any examples of using the SDK to logon as an app and post and/or get scores? Thank you.

P.S. This post is a bit like [How to post as application to facebook wall, using Facebook C# SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431544/how-to-post-as-application-to-facebook-wall-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk) but that post remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Users log in to your app / game using FB credentials and permit your app to post on their wall. The code in your app will post on their wall as them.

Comment: This is how you post a story to their wall on behalf of the app not how you post a Score which is different. (please check the links in the OP).